# What is a state pair?

Tags: meaning

In the beginning of the first chapter of *The Adventures of Tom Sawyer* by Mark Twain I read:

> The old lady pulled her spectacles down and looked over them about the room; then she put them up and looked out under them. She seldom or never looked through them for so small a thing as a boy; they were her **state pair**, the pride of her heart, and were built for "style," not service -- she could have seen through a pair of stove-lids just as well.

So what does **state pair** exactly mean and what is the etymology of this collocation?

Comment: *Pair* is *pair of spectacles.*  I can only guess about *state.*

Comment: @phoog So it must mean ceremonial spectacles, so to speak?

Comment: Yes, I suppose so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *OED* records several shades of meaning for "state" as having high status and accompanied by suitable pomp.  These are mostly obsolete and survive in usages like "a **state** dinner held at the White House."

So the "state pair" of glasses is a ceremonial pair reserved for special social occasions.